# Run Hello World (parallel) in Unix Shell

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to run this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
int id, np;
char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
nt processor_name_len;

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &np);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);
MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &processor_name_len);

printf("Hello world from process %03d out of %03d, processor name %s\n", 
id, np, processor_name);

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

The compilation works with:

mpicc hello_parallel.c -o hello_parallel

but I can't run it with ./hello_parallel

Comment: @H2CO3 : I think he meant to say could not have able to run it

Comment: What does "can't run it" mean? *Something* happens when you type `./hello_parallel`; don't make us guess what that is.

Comment: @Omkant: I hope not; that would be less clear than what he wrote.

Comment: I'm becoming more and more certain that I should *really* take a mind-reading course before continuing my career on StackOverflow.

Comment: @H2CO3, I've bought a professional crystal ball at an auction at the nearby house of magicians. Was quite cheap, but works like charm (only hat to bring it once for mana battery replacement).

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to execute a MPI application, you will likely want to run it with mpirun:

```
mpirun -np 2 ./hello_parallel
```

Where 2 in this case is the number of processes to run.  Often there are additional steps to set up the MPI cluster before that will work (`lamboot` for LAM MPI), but those are MPI implementation dependent.

Comment: Better these days to use the standard `mpiexec` which ought to be portable across MPI implementations